# Not able to run viewer

Tags: javascript, autodesk-forge, autodesk, autodesk-viewer

I am developing website with help of autodesk api . Viewer was working properly yesterday but it is showing error now. Please help me
*This is error*
developer.api.autodesk.com/viewingservice/v1/items/urn:adsk.viewing:fs.file…TVEVQ/output/1/battery%20holder.svf?domain=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A3000:1

GET https://developer.api.autodesk.com/viewingservice/v1/items/urn:adsk.viewing…i5TVEVQ/output/1/battery%20holder.svf?domain=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A3000 404

onLoadModelError() - errorCode:5

Comment: The error code 5 stands for `The derivative file has been moved or deleted`.  Please check your file is still in your Forge bucket, or check your access token has the right scope and the right permission.

Answer (score 1):

The error code 5 stands for The derivative file has been moved or deleted. Please check your file is still in your Forge bucket, or check your access token has the right scope and the right permission.

If you still stuck on this issue, please contact with the `forge.help@auotdesk.com`.